# CSS3 transform on page load

Tags: css, fade

Hey my question is how they made that, that the bar over and under the text fade in when the site is displayed ?

http://joy-interactive.com/

-Kai

Comment: Like I'm gonna click that...

Comment: what browser do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

They probably set a jQuery event to automatically trigger the animation upon `$( document ).ready`

```
$(function() {  

  $("#progress-bar").toggleClass("top-bar-animation");  

});
```

And then in their CSS, they have something like:

```
.top-bar-animation {  
  //animation code here
}
```

Comment: I don't mean the loading animation I mean the bars under an over the text: High level... here's a screenshot of the code:http://prntscr.com/2su2ta but the class .started I don't found in the html code so I don't know how I can make this..